# Setting charset for Open Api 3.0 / Swagger v3

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I use Cyrillic symbols in my project.

My way to read Cyrillic symbols from the swagger-message.properties is here:

```
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource translator() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasenames("swagger-message");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }
```

I want not to translate my words to unicode symbols. Is it possible to set encoding like UTF-8 for the beans?

Answer (score 1):

I've already found the answer:

```
source.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
```

I just needed to add default encoding using the method