# how to set encoding utf-8 in swagger ui for v3/api-docs?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi-generator, springdoc

My documentation is generated using swagger UI. But I have a problem with the language. How do I set the language encoding?

**v3/api-docs**

[image]

Comment: JSON almost exclusively uses UTF-8, so I suspect the problem is in how you read the file. What editor do you use to open the file? Did you specify an encoding when you did? If that's *not* the problem, then it's probably on the reading side (i.e. wherever that text came from is already *read* wrong).

Answer (score 2):

I found two answers for this question, Hope that they will help you. One is for application yaml:

```
server:
 servlet:
   encoding:
    force-response: true
    charset: UTF-8
```

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3544

And the other is this [Setting charset for Open Api 3.0 / Swagger v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620013/setting-charset-for-open-api-3-0-swagger-v3)

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource translator() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("swagger-message");
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    source.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return source;
}
```

[Setting charset for Open Api 3.0 / Swagger v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620013/setting-charset-for-open-api-3-0-swagger-v3)

Comment: Thank you very much! The first solution helped me! I also did this, but did not specify the force-response setting. What does it mean?